# Regex: Match integers inside of expressions

Tags: python, regex

I am interested in searching for integers inside of expressions using the Python re module.  For instance given the string

```
1e2 - variabl3e+2 + atan2(8/3.0, -1.)
                ^         ^
```

I would like to extract the `2` and the `8`.  As a starting point I have

```
(?<![a-zA-Z_.])(?<![eE][-+])(\d+)(?![eE.])
```

which uses negative lookahead and lookbehind to exclude integers which form either part of a floating point number or a variable/function.  The issue is that this excludes the `2` in `variabl3e+2` on account of the `e+2` bit making it appear as if the `2` is a floating point exponent.

However, without variable width negative lookbehind I can not think of a means of handling this case.

Comment: Why are you trying to parse this with regex? If it's valid Python code, using e.g. [`ast.parse`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/ast.html#ast.parse) would be easier.

Comment: It is not Python code.  Some aspects will not pass through ast.parse.

Comment: Then what *is* it? Could you be using e.g. `pyparse` to parse it properly, rather than regex?

Comment: You've tagged it with `python`. It is very misleading if it's not Python code.

Comment: @colidyre it's tagged python because OP wants to use a Python regex.

Answer (score 0):

You can match numbers that are not preceded or followed by letters or dots.

```
[^\w\.-](\d+)[^\w\.-]
```

This regex pass simple tests. https://regex101.com/r/tV3zZ1/2

As [@jonrsharpe said](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32948424/regex-match-integers-inside-of-expressions#comment53721474_32948424), you are safer to use a real parser.

Comment: But that will match, say, the `3` in `2e-3` which is a fragment of a floating point number.

Comment: Yeah I just based my answer on your short code, but it can be extended, again it very prone to errors to try to do it with regex. I edit my answer to include your scenario.

Answer (score 0):

```
match = re.search(r'e[+-](\d).+\W\w+\((\d)',st)

if match is not None:
    print(match.groups())
else:
     print("no match")

('2', '8')
```

Comment: This could lead to `AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'groups'` if re.search hasn't found a valid string. You have to proof first if re.search is not None.